# acces violation at address 004A478. read of address 00000030

Tags: delphi-7

acces violation at address 004A478. read of address 00000030.  Can someone please help me on how to get around this problem. 
Im creating a program for a project where a user will be able to book for seats using a stringgrid.
when i click on the first title for the user to book it works perfectly but as soon as i click the second title to book it shows the error 'access violation at address 004A478. Read of address 00000030.
The code that i am using is:

```
for iCol := 1 to 11
 do
  begin
   for iRow := 1 to iCountRow
    do
     begin
       stgSeats2.Cells[iCol, iRow] := arrTitle2[iRow, iCol];
     end;
  end;
```

When i try to 'trace into' or 'step over' the error it brings me to this code.
help will really be appreciated.

Comment: You should post some code, there's **nothing** that could help us helping you in your question. See [mcve]

Comment: Why not do some debugging? Start by finding out what the error message means. As soon as you know the will be simple to solve the problem.

Comment: After doing some debugging i got a new error 'access violation ADDRESS AT 0045423E'

Comment: `stgSeats2.Cells` uses 0-based indexes, but you are passing it 1-based indexes instead.

Comment: Debugging doesn't mean change code at random and report new error messages. In the six hours since I last posted, have you managed to work out what the error message means?

Answer (score 0):

```
for iCol := 1 to 11
 do
  begin
   for iRow := 1 to iCountRow
    do
     begin
       stgSeats2.Cells[iCol-1, iRow-1] := arrTitle2[iRow-1, iCol-1];
     end;
  end;
```

Also make sure that you really have 11 Columns in both stgSeats2 and arrTitle2 :)

Answer (score 0):

Access Violation means that you are trying to access an unavailable resource.

Example: If you have 10 columns and try to access grid[10,x], delphi will raise an exception, because the index of columns starts with 0 and column 10 doesnt exists, i recommend that you debugg and look in wich part the runtime raises the acess violation exception;

So you will have a clue of wich resource delphi is trying to access and fix the error